# DAX AVERAGE % SAVED IN A MATRIX FOR GROUP AND SUB-GROUP (ENTITY X USERS) Powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need the average % discount of a group of condominiums taking into account the following rule

Add the monthly average totals of discounts for each person, and divide by the total nr of months of all the people in the condominium, that is, if person A made transactions in 4 months, and B made it in 2 months, and C made it in 4 months, the total number of months is 10. So, to get the average, just take the accumulated total of the % saved and divide by these 10 months.

I have the correct average for people (sum of monthly averages, divided by the number of months), using the following DAX codes

Redução Tx do Usuário =
AVERAGEX(
KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('Dcalendario'[MesAno])),
CALCULATE([% ECONOMIZADO USUARIO])
)

where % user saved is the following DAX measure

% ECONOMIZADO USUARIO =
IF(
NOT(HASONEVALUE(clientes[Nome])),
AVERAGEX(
VALUES(clientes[Nome]),
[media economizado tx]
),
[media economizado tx]

where the average saved is the division of the penultimate column by the second, on 11.08.2021, the value is 0.10 divided by 325.00 = 0.10%

In the case of the image that I present to improve understanding, the % discount for Alcantara (condominium) is presented as 1.5%, when the correct one would be 1.12%

The total average of users, in this case, is 11.25%, divided by 10 months, which is the sum of the months in which transactions occurred by all users of this condominium, giving an average of 1.12%, the final objective is to have the average of each condominium and of the other condominiums that participate in the calculation, keeping the information of the average per user, and per month (both are already ok).

[Value is wrong at condominium level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYQaJ.jpg)

In this case, for the Alcantara calculation to be ok, I have to add the % of Aline + the % of Edevilson and 2 other people, which will total 11.25 and divide by 10 months (Aline's 4 months, Aline's 2 months Edevilson and 2 other people with 2 months each).

How should the DAX code be correct, so that the group total is ok, keeping the average number of people who are already ok?

And how can I get the total of these months (sum) to present on a card, I want the grand total of months of all transactions (sum of the months of each user).

Comment: It’s difficult to understand the scenario.  It would help is you can provide simplified sample data and desired results.

Comment: https://files.xbmcbrasil.net/Suporte/bi2.zip

Get the bi + 3 excel files (1 condominium, 1 customer, 1 transaction).

Here I have now total months, in one card work now to show the result to condominium level, don´t work in the matrix.

with this, I arrive at the result of 1.25% on average for this condominium X and 1.03 for condominium B .

Comment: But the average of all condominiums is not a sum of these results, so I have to take the sum of the averages of each condominium and still divide by the nr of condominiums, that is 1.25% of the cond. X + 1.03% condominium B, will be equal to 1.03% condominiums = 1.03% which is the final result of what I need.

Comment: Is have one way to get the 1,25% to A and 1,03 to B in the Matrix to Condominium Level is the question. 
Grand Total need Sum Average each Condominium Divided by Total Condominiums = Average % Saved.